# IntPtr.Size shows OS version or .NET version?

Tags: .net, 64-bit

Does the results of IntPtr.Size show the OS that the .NET app is running on or which version of .NET Framework that is running?  If you have a 32-bit app running on a 64-bit machine using WOW, what will IntPtr.Size show (4 or 8)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It returns the bitness of the current *process*.

Therefore, if your assembly is compiled as x86 only, it will always return 4, even on an x64 OS.

Comment: So you are saying that it will return 4 since the process is 32-bit, even though it is running on a 64-bit machine?

Comment: @user54064 Yes that is what SLaks is saying

Comment: Yes.  If the process is 32-bit, it will return 4.